# Difference between getPathParameters() & getQueryParameters()

Tags: java, web-services

I am new to Web service & while creating web service which accepts GET request, I found 2 methods by which I can read URL parameters:

getPathParameters() & getQueryParameters() of UriInfo. When I tried executing both I got same output. Here is the code I tried to run:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public String processGETReq(@Context UriInfo pUriInfo) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = pUriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParams = pUriInfo.getPathParameters();
    Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> lQueryParamsSet = queryParams.entrySet();
    Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> lPathParamsSet = pathParams.entrySet();

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> lQueryEntrySet : lQueryParamsSet) {
        System.out.println(lQueryEntrySet.getValue());
        System.out.println(lQueryEntrySet.getKey());
    }

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> lPathEntrySet : lPathParamsSet) {
        System.out.println(lPathEntrySet.getValue());
       System.out.println(lPathEntrySet.getKey());
    }
}
```

The output for both are same. So, I am curious to know what is the difference between them. Tried to get it from documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) but didn't get the difference properly.

Thanks in advance for answers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/clients/123/sales?sort=asc
```

`clientId=123` is a path parameter, `sort=asc` is a query parameter.

Comment: To be more precise: if the wbeservice defined it's url like `/clients/${clientid}/sales` then `/clients/123/sales?sort=asc` would have the path parameter `clientid = 123` and the query parameter `sort = asc`.